# Keyword "in" in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I don't understand how this code gets the value of "z":

```
let outer x y =
  let inner z = x + z
  in inner y ;;
```

In general, I can't understand how the "in" clause works when we have multiple functions.

Comment: `in ` is not an instruction, but a keyword .... Read [the Ocaml manual](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/index.html). BTW, I don't understand your question. Study also the source code of open source programs (including the Ocaml standard library) coded in Ocaml for inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `let inner z = x + z` is equivalent to (or syntactic sugar for)

```
 let inner = fun z -> x + z
```

Refer to [the Chapter 1 - the core language](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/coreexamples.html) and section [§7.7 Expressions](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/expr.html) of Ocaml manual.

Hence your `inner y` function application (in the last line) binds `z` to the value of `y` ...